# loop through the json url

Tags: c#, json, loops

I got a json Url but I've got more Forenames in it. Right now it only shows one Forename.

```
    public class details
    {

        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int lID { get; set; }
        public string uuid { get; set; }
        public string wpUID { get; set; }
        public string fname { get; set; }

    }
       private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){

       var json1 = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://dev.ibeaconlivinglab.com:1881/showemployeesbyhu  
       urders?id=" + companyID);


        List<details> detailsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<details>>(json1);

        foreach (details dets1 in detailsList)
        {

            label3.Text = dets1.fname;
            this.Controls.Add(label3);

        }
```

}

Json :

[
  {
  "id": 1,
  "fname": "Jeff",
  },
  {
  "id": 1,
  "fname": "Jan",
  },
  {
  "id": 1,
  "fname": "Piet",
  }
]

Comment: Did you try to debug the json string returned by the server with the help of  `console.log(json1)`?

Comment: @daniela yeh I did

Answer (score 2):

Problem is code is updating the *same* `label` again and again.

Try creating new `Label` each `detail`.

```
FlowLayoutPanel flowLayoutPanel1 = new FlowLayoutPanel();
flowLayoutPanel1.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
flowLayoutPanel1.WrapContents = false;
flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;

this.Controls.Add(flowLayoutPanel1);

foreach (details dets1 in detailsList) 
{ 
    var label = new Label(); 
    label.Name = dets1.fname; 
    label.Text = dets1.fname; 
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(label);   
}
```

Comment: I just tried that and I got the same name twice as result.

Comment: Will you able to see any other name?

Comment: No I see the name ""jeff"" twice

Comment: I copied :     var label = new Label();
    label.Name = dets1.fname; // try keeping it unique.
    label.Text = dets1.fname;

    this.Controls.Add(label); and changed label name to label1

Comment: I don't see any reason it is showing only two with same name, your json is having 3 entries, so you should see 3 Labels.

Comment: This is the code I have right now. foreach (details dets1 in detailsList)
            {
                var label = new Label();
                label.Name = dets1.fname;
                label.Text = dets1.fname;

                this.Controls.Add(label);
                label.Location = new Point(13, 30);

                var labelone = new Label();
                labelone.Name = dets1.fname;
                labelone.Text = dets1.fname;

                this.Controls.Add(labelone);
                labelone.Location = new Point(13, 50);
            }

Comment: and here the result as image : https://gyazo.com/a6970c2c99ded2c45e3425f2f0664da9

Comment: It worked !!! but as you can see I want to have every username among each other so I can set the button right to them.

Comment: You could do that adding one more (nested) `flowlayout` control and label and button together.

Comment: If you can't solve the problem, I would suggest close this question(as answer) and open a new question. It may confuse users having similar problems, so it should be question to answer always. Hope you understand.